# Using CSS Sprites and repeat-x background-position with transparent pixels

Tags: css, size, height, background-image

I'm asking exactly what the title says...

```
#submenu-outer{
    height:40px;
    background: #F0EFE2 url(/template/img/main/intro12.png) 0px -240px repeat-x;
    width:100%;
}
```

That code makes no sense; Any suggestions?
I want to repeat the first column of this line.
Every other line (of 40px) is null there (0px -240px)

Comment: Hi, can you make a jsfiddle so we can see what you are trying to achieve? Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense. Could you include an image of what you are trying to achieve? When you say `That code makes no sense` - what do you mean exactly? You don't understand what it is doing?

Comment: You posted some code, and said it "makes no sense". So why did you post it? What is it from? What do you want with it? Try to describe the problem, rather than a solution which doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `repeat-x` as background position it will repeat the whole width of the image file. So if you have transparent pixels in your sprite after 40px, it's actually normal that you get some transparent background every 40px or so.

You could either make your repeating pattern take the whole sprite width, or put it in a seperate file.